Unable to add Text Selection Context Menu Button Item in SelectableRegion or SelectionArea
I want to have an additional button in the text selection popup buttons shows up on tap and holding the text.
Selection text will be inside a text widget or any other widget but NOT an Editable field like an input form field. I tried various things but neither of them showed a mismatch lint/syntax error or the button itself.
End Goal:
I want to Select the text from a Text Widget (Not a FormField) and have an additional button to perform an action.

I tried:
https://zenn.dev/taki/articles/9feff78e2b2503
plus more variations I also tried SelectableRegion, still not working.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorSchemeSeed: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String? selectedText;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Selection Area'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          //  I tried SelectableRegion as well, still not working
          child: SelectionArea(
              onSelectionChanged: (final value) {
                print(value?.plainText);
                setState(() {
                  selectedText = value?.plainText;
                });
              },
              contextMenuBuilder: (context, selectableRegionState) {
                final extraButton = ContextMenuButtonItem(
                    label: 'Extra Button',
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if (selectedText == null) return;
                    });
                return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.buttonItems(buttonItems: [
                  extraButton,
                  ...selectableRegionState.contextMenuButtonItems
                ], anchors: selectableRegionState.contextMenuAnchors);
              },
              child: const Text(
                '!!! Select Part of Me !!!',
              ) // This could be any widget tree, as I'm not selecting from a direct string,
            ),
        ));
  }
}



Try SelectableText widget to select your text

Unfortunately, That takes direct String as input/child, not a widget.

try SelectableText.rich with "WidgetSpan" widget as a children of textspan
add your desired widget as a child of WidgetSpan
